# The antonym of "rule lawyering"

Tags: antonyms

Wikipedia defines [rule lawyers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_lawyer) as

> A rules lawyer is a participant in a rules-based environment who attempts to use the letter of the law without reference to the spirit

TV Tropes has an [in-depth description of the rule lawyer archetype](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RulesLawyer) as depicted in media as well.

Their behavior is usually called "rule lawyering".

I am writing a blog post where I want to describe an environment where people, instead, have the opposite attitude: being focused on the spirit of the rules and not on the wording.

Is there a name or way of expressing this in a concise and effective way, like a word or two?

Comment: Do you remember 'Rumphole of the Bailey'?

Comment: A free spirit is someone who doesn't necessarily follow all the rules. https://www.thefreedictionary.com/free+spirit Not sure if it fits. You can contrast rules lawyer with free spirit, emphasising the spirit of the law. Or how about "latitudinarian", often an Anglican term, but can be otherwise. " 1. characterized by latitude in opinion or conduct.  You could contrast a rules lawyer with a law latitudinarian.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't, as far as I know, a direct antonym to "rules lawyer". This is because a rules lawyer is seen as unusual, hence anyone who isn't a rules lawyer is just a "normal human being".

There are two phrases I can think of which are opposite to "rule lawyering". There is, as you've mentioned "spirit of the rules", or you could talk about taking a "balanced approach"; where you are "balancing" the need for rules to define the framework against the tediousness and joy-killing rigid adherence to them. Unfortunately neither of these phrases is stand-alone, and would need some other words around it. For example:

> Instead of rule-lawyering, this group preferred to take a balanced approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you are *narrowly* focused on rules, then you lose sight of the well-being of the people involved. (I.e., the law becomes something of a game with winning and losing moves rather than a statement about human need. Although in some cases, this can still be good for a particular client in the right context.)

Somebody who is focused on the well-being of people is a **humanist**.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [humanism](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/humanism):

> **2** : devotion to human welfare : HUMANITARIANISM
> // renowned for his *humanism*
>
> **3** : a doctrine, attitude, or way of life centered on human interests or values
> *especially* : a philosophy that usually rejects supernaturalism and stresses an individual's dignity and worth and capacity for self-realization through reason
>
> // Chay Yew directs this world premiere with a warmth and generosity that matches the *humanism* and balance of the script.
> — Chris Jones, *chicagotribune.com*, "'Lettie' at Victory Gardens: A mother's years lost to prison are years she can't get back," 17 Apr. 2018

A lawyer who approaches a case in a humanistic fashion may well argue for or against some rules not just because of their effect on their client's case but because of how much they think they do or don't express the spirit of a situation.

Such a lawyer would be the type who would conclude a movie or TV episode with a passionate speech about forgetting about the rules and doing what's fair.

Comment: 1. A rules lawyer is not a lawyer, using a lawyer as an example really isn't good. All actual lawyers *have* to be "rules lawyers". 2. I'm not sure "humanist" really works. To me "humanist" is closely related to "atheist"; along the lines of your quote *"especially : a philosophy that usually rejects supernaturalism"*.